# Understand Graph solution for Word Search 2 Leetode

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

```
class Solution:
    def findWords(self, board: List[List[str]], words: List[str]) -> List[str]:
        WORD_KEY = '$'  
        trie = {}
        for word in words:
            node = trie
            for letter in word:
                # retrieve the next node; If not found, create a empty node.
                node = node.setdefault(letter, {})
            # mark the existence of a word in trie node
            node[WORD_KEY] = word        
        rowNum = len(board)
        colNum = len(board[0])        
        matchedWords = []        
        def backtracking(row, col, parent):                
            letter = board[row][col]
            currNode = parent[letter]            
            # check if we find a match of word
            word_match = currNode.pop(WORD_KEY, False)
            if word_match:
                # also we removed the matched word to avoid duplicates,
                #   as well as avoiding using set() for results.
                matchedWords.append(word_match)            
            # Before the EXPLORATION, mark the cell as visited 
            board[row][col] = '#'            
            # Explore the neighbors in 4 directions, i.e. up, right, down, left
            for (rowOffset, colOffset) in [(-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1)]:
                newRow, newCol = row + rowOffset, col + colOffset     
                if newRow < 0 or newRow >= rowNum or newCol < 0 or newCol >= colNum:
                    continue
                if not board[newRow][newCol] in currNode:
                    continue
                backtracking(newRow, newCol, currNode)        
            # End of EXPLORATION, we restore the cell
            board[row][col] = letter       
            # Optimization: incrementally remove the matched leaf node in Trie.
            if not currNode:
                parent.pop(letter)
        for row in range(rowNum):
            for col in range(colNum):
                # starting from each of the cells
                if board[row][col] in trie:
                    backtracking(row, col, trie)        
        return matchedWords
```

I don't understand how does trie store the data structure. From the snippet:

```
for word in words:
                node = trie
                for letter in word:
                    # retrieve the next node; If not found, create a empty node.
                    node = node.setdefault(letter, {})
                # mark the existence of a word in trie node
                node[WORD_KEY] = word
```

node should be storing the data structure (example {o:{a:{t:{h:{$:'oath'}}}}}, etc) and not trie. However, when I debug the code I see this data structure being stored in both node and trie.

Comment: *"node should be storing the data structure (example {o:{a:{t:{h:{$:'oath'}}}}} and not trie."*: why do you say *"not trie"*? Of course it should be stored **in** `trie`.

Comment: I do not understand this part. The for loop stores the 'letter dictionary' in 'node'. I don't see any assignment on 'trie' variable. Could you please help me understand this?

Answer (score 0):

`trie` is the root node, it only has to get a value once, and after that it should never change again. So at the start of the code you have this initialisation of `trie`:

```
trie = {}
```

The variable `node` on the other hand, is a kind of pointer that walks through the existing nodes within the trie in order to inspect the letters that are there. It always starts pointing at the root, and so we have:

```
node = trie
```

Then in the loop it walks deeper into the trie, either following an existing child node, or creating a new one if it didn't exist yet. All this happens in this one statement:

```
node = node.setdefault(letter, {})
```

This is short for the following three statements:

```
if letter not in node:  # property letter does not yet exist here...
    node[letter] = {}  # create it, and attach a new node to it, extending trie
node = node[letter]  # move the pointer to that new node
```

As `node` walks through the trie and sometimes extends an existing node with a new child node, we are actually mutating what is (deep) inside `trie`. This is typical for nested object structures: you can make those objects more nested without ever having to assign anything directly to the variable that has the top-level object.

#### Example

Let's say only one word is added in a trie; the word "bar". Here is what happens:

First `tree = {}` is executed.

The outer loop iterates over the words. Since we only have one, there will be just one iteration.

Then `node = tree` is executed. So we now have two references to the same, empty dictionary:

```
{}  # this is: trie, and also: node
```

The inner loop iterates three times. First `letter` is "b".

`setdefault` detects that `node` has no property "b", so it creates it. This mutates `node` which now changes from `{}` to `{ "b": {} }`. Realise that `node` and `trie` are referencing the *same* dictionary at this moment, so this is also what `trie` is:

```
{  # this is: trie, also: node
    "b": {}
}
```

Then, in the same statement, `node` gets assigned the value of this new property "b", which is `{}`. Now `trie` and `node` are no longer the same reference:

```
{  # this is: trie
    "b": {}  # this is: node
}
```

We go to the next iteration. Now `letter` is "a". Again, `setdefault` detects that `node` has no "a" property (it is an empty dictionary), and so that property is created with a new, empty dictionary as value. We get this situation

```
{  # this is: trie
    "b": {  # this is: node
        "a": {}
    }
}
```

And again, in the same statement, `node` is assigned that newly created dictionary:

```
{  # this is: trie
    "b": {
        "a": {}  # this is: node
    }
}
```

Similarly the same process adds "r" in the third iteration:

```
{  # this is: trie
    "b": {
        "a": {
            "r": {}  # this is: node
        }
    }
}
```

After the loop the following statement is executed:

```
node[WORD_KEY] = word
```

And so that deep dictionary also gets a property:

```
{  # this is: trie
    "b": {
        "a": {
            "r": {  # this is: node
                "$": "bar"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So you see how this process extends the original `trie` dictionary. It is still the same dictionary, as at the start, but it just has received a property with a dictionary as value, which in turn also got extended.

Comment: In the beginning of for loop, 'trie'={ }, I don't see any other assignment on 'trie'. So how does 'trie' store 'letter dictionary'

Comment: Like I wrote in my answer `trie` only needs to get an assignment once. All the rest is happening deeper within the `trie`. Compare it to adding elements to a stack: you only need to define it once, and then you can just grow it without ever having to *assign* anything else to your stack variable.

Comment: I hope you read my answer with attention, as it is all there. I have added an example.